# How to chain axios get requests while response hasMore flag is true

Tags: javascript, api, axios

I am hitting an endpoint that gives me a list of users but the result is paginated. The response contains a flag `hasMore` which tells if there are more users to be retrieved and an `offset` to make the next api call with.

Right now I am able to make multiple calls by manually checking if the result `hasMore` is true. How do wrap this logic in a while loop?

```js
function getUsers() {
  let users = [];
  
  axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
      res.users.forEach(user => {
        users.push(user);
      })
      
      if (res.hasMore) {
        return axios.get(url + '&offset=' + res.offset)
      }
    })
    .then(res => // repeat what I've just done and keep checking hasMore
    // How do I check this in a while?
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you move the `users = []` up a level?

```
let users = [];

function getUsers(url) {

  axios
    .get(url)
    .then(res => {
      res.users.forEach(user => {
        users.push(user);
      })

      if (res.hasMore) {
        getUsers(url + '&offset=' + res.offset);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {...});
}
```

Comment: Ah a recursive approach... let me try

Comment: you'll need to format the second url obviously to use something like `baseURL` but seems like this should work

Comment: I've updated code to take your suggestion the second call is infinitely repeating with the same offset number...any idea why?

Comment: without seeing the network requests and data it's impossible for me to tell

Comment: Oh I was accidentally concatenating the offset with the same url I pass in every time so it would go &offset=xxxx&offset=xxxx infinitely... I have fixed it now and your solution worked. Thank you!